# 10x slower execution under XCode debug mode

Tags: objective-c, optimization, xcode6

I am running a compute intensive iOS app and in debug mode it runs 10x (!) slower. This appears to be due to the Optimization Level which is set to "None [-Oo]" in DEBUG build and "Fastest, Smallest [-Os]" in RELEASE build. The trouble is that setting Optimization Level to "Fastest, Smallest [-Os]" in DEBUG kills all manners of debugging, including examining variables. This appears to be new in XCode 6 and I doubt that disabling optimizations accounts for a 10x slowdown. Could there be another DEBUG build setting triggered when optimizations are disabled which dramatically slows execution?

I should mention that one other function actually takes 100x (not 10x) even though all it does is apply some Regexes (using a compiled PCRE library). 100x is just too large to be normal AND note that in that instance it links with the same pcre.a library whether in DEBUG or RELEASE. Clearly the heavy lifting in that case in within the PCRE code in pcre.a so (not the C++ code in the iOS app which calls it) so how is it possible that this same (compiled) code runs slower when the (thin) calling app code is compiled in DEBUG mode?

Comment: Of _course_ debug mode can be slower. What do you expect? You whould not be measuring / concerned with speed when in debug mode. What's the question?

Comment: True, please see comment I added to explain why there is something very wrong, much beyond what turning optimizations off could explain.

Comment: If you want to know what's taking time, use Instruments; that's what it's for. But it is pointless to worry about time optimizations except in a release build. So I still don't see what you're asking.

Comment: I agree in general, the issue is that 100x is such a drag that it makes debugging very time consuming - think 10s instead of 0.1s to execute one function + it feels like something is wrong when that happens with very simple compiled code calling a pre-compiled library (PCRE), where 99% of the complexity resides and whose performance shouldn't be affected at all by debug/release build of the app itself. I was hoping this extreme situation would strike a bell with someone who found what caused this.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have similar issue. In my case, I have the problem just after edit the storyboard. I did not found a solution. So if you found, please notice.